# Which integer sequence starts with small elements, and stays there for a (really) long time, but eventually escapes the initial area?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, oeis

Graphically, I am searching for something like this:

[image]

The only additional requirement would be that the elements are defined by a closed formula or "simple" recursion, i.e. no definition by cases (Fallunterscheidung) and such.

Comment: What do you mean by "which"? There are a huge number of such sequences. Do you want to know how many there are? A general way to find them? A way to find all of them?

Comment: If you just want an example, I'd go for something like $\lfloor 10^{n-10}\rfloor$.  That one stays at $0$ for $10$ terms, then explodes.  $\lfloor 10^{n-100}\rfloor$ stays at $0$ for $100$ terms then explodes.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I didn't think of that. Do you eventually know of one that is defined by recursion?

Comment: Sure.  $a_i=0$ for $i<100$, $a_{100}=1$ and $a_i=10a_{i-1}$ for $i>100$.

Comment: @lulu But that would be a case distinction, or not?

Comment: Well...all recursions have initial conditions.  You might ask for one with the minimal number of initial conditions...how about:  $a_i=0$ for $i\in \{1,\dots, 99\}$ $a_{100}=1$ and $a_i=10\times \sum_{k=i-100}^{i-1}a_i$ for $i>100$?

Comment: @lulu It looks like I'll have to work on the wording in English, but thank you for your time and input!

Comment: An issue that you will have to consider is the accuracy of your figures once you are at the million-th step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the same thing, but consider the "Tower of Hanoi" sequence:

1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 ...

$a_n = k$ when $n$ is an odd number times $2^{k-1}$

We need more than 1000 terms before we see any term greater than 10 (in the Tower of Hanoi puzzle that means if you have 11 layers you need over 1000 moves to expose the bottom disk).  Yet the sequence is ultimately unbounded.

Comment: Oh my god, this is perfect! Thank you! (Even though not expressed by a closed formula).

Answer (score 4):

How about $a_n=2^{n\cdot\lfloor{n/1000000}\rfloor}$?